# Mapstruct: update individual models in collection

Tags: java, collections, java-8, mapstruct

I am trying to update a collection using mapstruct like this:

```
List<Passenger> updatePassengers(@MappingTarget List<Passenger> passengers, List<Passenger> sourcePassenger);
Passenger updatePassenger(@MappingTarget Passenger passenger, Passenger sourcePassenger);
```

Now in generated sources updatePassenger method is generated as below:

```
public List<Passenger> updatePassengers(List<Passenger> passengers, List<Passenger> sourcePassenger) {
    if ( sourcePassenger == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    passengers.clear();
    for ( Passenger passenger : sourcePassenger ) {
        passengers.add( passenger );
    }

    return passengers;
}
```

Here its removing the passenger from the destination and setting passengers from source. I want to update individual passenger objects.

I went through the mapstruct docs and it says that it clears collection before updating.

Is there a way mapstruct could call updatePassenger method for each passenger?

Comment: Does wrapping the collection into another object and using the bean property as in [Example 43](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#mapping-collections) in the documentation help?

Comment: I don’t get the purpose of that construct. Since this is a generated method, it will never do something smarter than what we see here. So why on Earth should I ever invoke `updatePassenger(list1, list2)` instead of `list1.addAll(list2);`? It’s not like that generated method did anything better than that—it’s the opposite. The generated method has a broken `null` handling that creates a time bomb in your code might break at a later time and does an unnecessary manual loop where a better intrinsic Collection operation exist.

Comment: @Holger you are right, you would never want to invoke `updatePassenger(list1, list2)`. The OP uses the construct wrong. The idea of such methods is to be used by different source and target types and to be used by managed collections (using the same type makes no big sense). For example when updating JPA managed entities performing clear and adding new objects has some meaning. As for the broker `null` handling, if you are referring to the method returning `null` for a `Collection`, that can actually be configured in the definition of the mapper

Comment: @Filip: I was referring to the fact that this method receives the target collection, returns the same collection *or `null`* while not being capable of handling a `null` target collection on its own. So its introducing a nullability to something it does consider itself to be always non-null. This inconsistency is even worse than using nullable collections in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you don't want the default behaviour of MapStruct kicking in you should write your own custom method that would perform the update.

```
default List<Passenger updatePassengers(List<Passenger> passenger, Lit<Passenger> sourcePassengers) {
    //Do your logic here
}
```

On top of that, MapStruct cannot generate the code you need it doesn't know which passenger should be linked with which passenger.

In your definition you are saying that you want the `passenger` list to be update with the `sourcePassengers` list.

Comment: Any other option, in latest versions of MapStruct to achieve this ? @Filip

Comment: What kind of other option are you looking for? Is it about the default method or something else?

Comment: @Filip couldn't MapStruct automate this by making equality checks on each element of the list (comparing source and destination) to find if it already exists, and if it does then use the individual `update` method, else use the individual `create` method? That seems like a valid approach, so I guess MapStruct, a few years after this answer was provided, might now support such feature. I personally would love this because we use DTOs to update JPA entities which already populate a list: the Primary Key can thus be used to know which entity to update.

Comment: Perhaps it could that in the future, but that's not how it works now and there are no plans to change that.

Comment: @payne and @Filip this is a great idea to use Java "equals" check and `update` or `create` accordingly the target collection item! Will save lots of time for the MapStruct users!
for example a new annotation mode can be introduced:
`Mapping(collectionMatchStrategy = CollectionMatchStrategy.EQUALS)`